# Check if a result set has specific values

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-ce-4

I want to know what is the best way to check if a subquery has a set of values. I came up with the following query but I don't think its efficient.

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable 
WHERE 
(
    2 IN (SELECT OptionId FROM Table2 WHERE Table2_Id = 1) AND
    3 IN (SELECT OptionId FROM Table2 WHERE Table2_Id = 1)
)
```

I appreciate if anyone can provide me with a better solution.

Thanks

Comment: your query will eather return no rows or all rows. Maybe you should describe what you need

Comment: Assume I have an entity that can have some options, I want to get entities that have at least specified options (in this sample 2 and 3).

Comment: No matter which numbers you put in to replace 2 and 3. You will eather get all rows or no rows from Sometable. I believe you need a different result. Describe what you need and the relation between SomeTable and Table2

Comment: I have an Entities Table which has a many to many relation with Options table which results in a middle table that in the sample I called it Table2. I want to get all entities that have options with id 2 AND 3.

Comment: If the query I came up with is incorrect, I appreciate if you can provide a correct query for the above question.

Comment: I can't write your query without the tablestructure

Comment: @Mohammadreza: You should post the real problem not something which is a half solution without depicting the full problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `EXISTS` subqueries:

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE Table2_Id = 1 AND OptionId = 2) 
AND   EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE Table2_Id = 1 AND OptionId = 3)
```

If you have one of the following indexes `(Table2_Id,OptionId)` or `(OptionId,Table2_Id)` then you shouldn't have worries about performance.

**Edit 1:** After reading above comments I think you should JOIN somehow `SomeTable` with `Table2` using a common column thus:

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable x
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table2 y WHERE y.Table2_Id = 1 AND y.OptionId = 2 AND x.CommonColumn = y.CommonColumn) 
AND   EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table2 y WHERE y.Table2_Id = 1 AND y.OptionId = 3 AND x.CommonColumn = y.CommonColumn)
```

If this doesn't solve your problem then you should add more infos.